# P-dialog is not closing on outside screen click in the mobile app screen

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am showing P-dialog in the image click.When I click/select out side the dialog in the app screen the dialog is not closing.

How to close p-dialog on any selection of place in the screen i.e outside of the dialog?

Comment: P-Dialog means? are you referring this http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml show some code in html

Comment: Means DialogModule from 'primeng/dialog'

Answer (score 12):

You can set flag `[dismissableMask]="true"` to close the modal on clicking outside.

`<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" [dismissableMask]="true"></p-dialog>`

Comment: It doesn't work until I add [modal]="true". Can it work without adding this property ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p-dialog [(visible)]="display" [modal]="true">
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].